# Use AzCopy in Azure Automation Job

Tags: azure

Is it possible to use AzCopy in an Azure Automation job? Is it possible to wrap AzCopy in a Powershell Module and upload that?

Comment: Great question. I'm looking forward to answers to this. I haven't tried to use this in Azure Automation but my understanding is that this API acts like azcopy. This may be worth some research. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-storage-data-movement-library-preview-2/

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this or an alternate solution?

Comment: No, I never found an answer for this. We were wanting to make copies of Azure file shares, so we ended up creating new file shares and then copying the content over file by file.

Comment: @DanO'Leary See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881948/start-azurestorageblobcopy-vs-azcopy-which-one-takes-lesser-time/50651544#50651544 - While technically not AzCopy, I was able to get the performance of `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy` to work at similar performance what I suspect AzCopy would run at in Azure Automation. That aside, Azure Automation jobs won't run exe files (which AzCopy is).

Answer (score 1):

With the AzCopy, you should upload the Storage Tools, as AzCopy will not work without them. That will make the work much more difficult.

There are manuals in the Internet on how to do that with the Powershell (without Automation, however): https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2016/02/17/upload-a-vhd-to-azure-storage-using-azcopy/
Microsoft has the Runbooks Gallery, and there are some Automation samples, but no Azcopy: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/a-Blob-from-Azure-Storage-6bc13745

And, as a "why?" question, is there are reason you want to use exact AzCopy? There is the Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy commandlet, which does almost the same, as both AzCopy and that commandlet invoke Async Server-Side Blob Copy operation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the storage tools. The reason I want to use AzCopy is that I need to copy an entire file share to a new file share, and there is no Azure cmdlet to do that.

Comment: **Why:** `AzCopy` appears to copy whole container in bulk, `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy` appears to function in a serial/for each fashion.

Comment: With AzCopy v10 you no longer need to install Storage Tools. V10 is just a single exe.  Please leave feedback at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues if you have any questions about authentication in automation scenarios