# Fastest way to move Azure VMS from one subscription on one account to another subscription in another account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, vhd

I have on my account one windows server with IIS and one OS disk which is 127gb.
I also have another sql server with the os disk also 127gb and 3 additional disks, one for the tempdb, another one for datafiles and another one for the logs.

The application is very critical, and we need to change it to another account. However the maintenance window cant be more than 2 hours.

What is the fastest way to copy the VHDS from one location to the other account?

I tried cloudberry explorer adding the storage accounts and just copying the files, but its been more than 5 minutes and it has only copies 5% of one 127GB file. 
Maybe this tool is using my computer as a temp location while it copies to the next storage account?

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to use AzCopy as below documentation link suggests.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/#blob-copy

If you have heard about PowerShell command `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy` it will give you almost same duration: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29888363/361100)

Another way is to use hands of Azure operator.

Submit a support ticket and they can help you to move a Storage to another subscription. If you prepare Virtual machine image, it will be achieved less than 1 hour downtime (hopefully?).